# How do I change the default text editor?

Tags: default-programs

How can I change my default text editor from gedit to Emacs?

Comment: It is answered here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/977538/16-04-crontab-e-editor-settings-python-syntax-highlighting-in-vim - basically you want to `export EDITOR=emacs` - and perhaps add that to your `.bashrc` so it becomes your default.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Here is what worked in my case:

1. Right click on a text file.
2. Choose "Properties" (not "Open With...")
3. Click on the "Open With" tab.
4. Choose your new text editor.
5. Mark chosen text editor using a button "Set as default".

This also works on 12.04 and 13.04.

@ Edit: based on comments it does work on all distros until 20.04

Comment: It does *not* work on 13.04. After Step 3, I see a lot of choices, but not the editor I would like to have .... of course, the idea would be to use 'Add' ... but this is grayed out and can't be selected. *Argh*

Comment: worked for me on 13.10 (replaced `gedit` with `geany`)

Comment: "Set as default" not showing on v 14

Comment: worked on 15.04 too !

Comment: Also works on 14.04

Comment: Works on 16.04 too!

Comment: Also works on 17.04

Comment: This works only on the per filetype basis..

Comment: Also works on 18.04

Comment: 18.04: `~/.config/mimeapps.list`

Comment: Should I do it for each type of file? There lots of 'types' of text file.

Comment: works with 20.04

Comment: Works on 20.04!

Comment: Doesn't work on 20.10....nah, kidding. Still works.

Comment: No surprise, it still works on 21.04

Comment: This only answers _"how do I change default editor for a specific file type"_, but doesn't answer how to _"change the default text editor for everything"_. See @kn_pavan's solution below for a good answer.

Comment: @Janos worked fine for me. But you have to do it twice. Once with a text file with no dot in the filename, and once with a text file with a dot.

Comment: Works on Mint 20.1. I went through "Open with" and "Open with other Application..."  instead of "Properties" though.

Answer (score 68):

To change default text editor across the file types, try updating gnome-text-editor configuration.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gnome-text-editor
```

In some cases:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

Comment: How can someone add another option? In my case I get the following: There is only one alternative in link group gnome-text-editor (providing /usr/bin/gnome-text-editor): /usr/bin/gedit - EDIT: found how to do it: `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gnome-text-editor gnome-text-editor /path/to/executablesublime 100` in my case `/snap/bin/subl` outoutted by `which subl`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Same here, I added `subl` first: `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gnome-text-editor gnome-text-editor $(which subl) 100`. Then it was already selected as editor, as the above command then confirmed.

Comment: This is the one you need to ensure your editor choice persists even when running programs using `wsl.exe <program>` in WSL. (Specifically `sudo update-alternatives --config editor`)

Answer (score 18):

I don't use a DE, but for my configurations the next command is the best:

```
/usr/bin/select-editor
```

- it selects your default sensible-editor from all installed editors
- must run with current user
- you must have more than one editor in your system

[Man pages `select-editor`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man1/select-editor.1.html)

Comment: +1 Works in 18.04. Does not affect other users. Does not need sudo.

Comment: After setting EDITOR to vi, VISUAL to vi, linking /etc/alternatives/editor or whatever to vi, I still got the pest named `nano` as the editor when running commands like `virsh edit myvm`. Applying a level of self-control I would never have guessed I could reach, I am not venting here. NOT VENTING AT ALL!!!! I renamed nano to nano.deleted, then I got several lines of error messages whenever I edited something. `select-editor` didn't change that. What did help was `rm /usr/bin/sensible-editor` followed by `ln -s /usr/bin/vi /usr/bin/sensible-editor`. Life is good.

Answer (score 15):

A more robust solution would be to replace the bindings in `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`.

```
sed -i 's/gedit/emacs/' /usr/share/applications/defaults.list
```

Comment: I don't know how, but by copying this command I accidentally cleared the whole file. I would much prefer doing this in a text editor using find-replace (as explained in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/98350/6418)) for those who are not too familiar with sed.

Comment: I did this (in a text editor with find-replace, which should have the same result), then logged out and back in but still C++ header files (*.h) are opened in gedit.

Answer (score 12):

Right click on a text file, point to "Open With" and it'll show other editors in a sub-menu. Click on "Other Application...". It'll show you a dialog with a list of applications, select Emacs and make sure the "Remember this application for "plain text document" file" option is checked. Click "Open".

Comment: I did try this, but I'm having a bit of a problem - whenever I double-click on a file in Nautilus, I get a dialog box that says: "Do you want to run "tasks.css", or display its contents? "tasks.css" is an executable text file." And then there are four options - Run in Terminal, Display, Cancel, Run. (This happens with every file, not just CSS files.)

Comment: @begtognen: Sorry for the ultra-late reply. But I've been trying to find a solution for this myself. Just found one - go to Nautlius preferences (Edit > Preferences), select the "Behavior" tab and under the "Executable Text Files" section, select the radio button "View executable text files when they are opened". Fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I tried this also, but Emacs doesn't appear in the list of applications. Any thoughts?

Comment: No "Remember this application" there. When outdated you might want to either delete your answer, or clearly specify for what versions of Ubuntu it works. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 9):

If you are working from the terminal then I would add the following to your .bashrc file (or the config file for your favorite shell):

```
export EDITOR=emacs
export VISUAL=emacs
```

Comment: +1 for this answer. Particularly if you're a user and don't have `sudo` or don't want to modify anyone else's preferences

Comment: Add these to `~/.bashrc` and run `source ~/.bashrc` to make this permanent.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the default text editor for a specific user in **# ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list** by:

```
[Default Applications]
text/plain=gedit.desktop
```

For global configuration for all users you have to modify the **/etc/gnome/defaults.list**

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -i 's/gedit/emacs/g' /etc/gnome/defaults.list
```

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 20, you need to change the `gnome-text-editor` alternatives link from `gedit` to the one you want. However, there usually is only one such editor detected so `update-alternatives --config` won't work; you'll have to *add* the editor you want.

E.g. to add `notepadqq`:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gnome-text-editor gnome-text-editor /usr/bin/notepadqq 50
sudo update-alternatives --config gnome-text-editor
```

Answer (score 3):

For some reason I had to use `xdg-mime`:

```bsh
xdg-mime default org.gnome.gedit.desktop text/plain # For current user
```

you can use your system-wide .desktop files under `/usr/share/applications/`
or local files under `~/.local/share/applications/` or [create your own](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en).

edit:
It's also helpful to know that user configurations are stored in `~/.config/mimeapps.list` which overrides the defaults.
source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64850938/9085151

Comment: Probably your application is opening the archive with xdg-open. To see if it is the case open htop in terminal without closing the opened file and find your open file in the tree.

Comment: @R.W.Prado I've changed my OS to debian since then, so I don't have access to that system anymore. But now I can easily change it with update-alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to replace gedit with any other text editor for all file types, the easiest is to edit the `defaults.list` file located here:

```
/usr/share/applications/defaults.list
```

Just find and replace all `gedit.desktop` references with your own editor (in this case `emacs.desktop`).
You need root permissions to edit the file. So, just do:

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/applications/defaults.list
```

Save the file, close it and it's done.

Answer (score -1):

To set Pluma as default text editor for all user (global):

```
sudo sed -i 's|text/plain=gedit.desktop|text/plain=pluma.desktop|g'  /etc/gnome/defaults.list
```