# How to make Quanta plus editor as a default editor?

Tags: default-programs

When I click on any file eg php file it open by default in gedit I want that it will open by default in quanta plus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the file -> select 'Properties' -> go to the 'Open With' tab -> select the text editor of your choice from the list.

I believe that will make the text editor you choose the default for that particular file type. You'll have to repeat those steps for every file type though (e.g. plain text file, .log, .txt, etc.)

Just saw, but this question was already answered in a general form here: [How do I change the default text editor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13447/how-do-i-change-the-default-text-editor)

Comment: Hmmm its great its doing work successfully but having bit issue  when i open two file then there two editor open.if i open 10 file than it will open one editor for each file mean open 10 editor.

Comment: I think this issue with opening multiple instances of the text editor instead of tabs (which it sounds like you want) is an issue with your text editor's settings, not with it being a default editor or not - so it's a different question. If this answer solved the question you ask please mark it as the accepted answer. If you have a new issue with your text editor please check your text editor's documentation and/or ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found to change mine to gvim (I think it should work the same for your editor) was to add text/plain=quanta.desktop to ~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list and restart nautilus.

Comment: ~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list not found this location

Comment: I m not found the defaults.list.Please reply its very urgent

Comment: If you don't have one but still have the ~/.local/share/applications, I'm pretty sure you can just create it.