# 16.04: crontab -e editor settings / Python syntax highlighting in vim

Tags: python, cron, text-editor, vi

`crontab -e` defaults to using `vi` for editing.

This is not usually a problem.  `vi` is an excellent editor, and easy to learn.

---

Recently I've begun to use `vim` which is installed by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vim
```

and in order to make it show line numbers and default to proper numbers of spaces when Tab is pressed, plus syntax highlighting for Python development,

the contents of my `/home/username/.vimrc` file is as so:

```
syntax enable
set number
set ts=4
set autoindent
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
set cursorline
set showmatch
let python_highlight_all = 1
```

This works out great.

---

However, when I use `crontab -e` it gives the following error messages:

> Sorry, the command is not available in this version: syntax enable
>
> Sorry, the command is not available in this version: let python_highlight_all = 1
>
> Press ENTER or type command to continue

Then pressing Enter allows it to continue into `vi` for editing of the cron table.

Questions:  What version of vi is it trying to use?  Is there a way to set it to the normal vim?  Or to set it to another editor?

Comment: The "version of `vi`" is exactly the same version of `vim` you are running when you type `vim`, except it is run in `vi`-compatible mode.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that.  In any case, the answer below solves the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the environment is checked with the `env` command

```
env
```

there is no default EDITOR specified.

Not wanting to waste time trying to figure out what version of `vi` it is trying to use, it seems better to simply solve the problem.

Thus, the solution is simple.

```
export EDITOR=gedit
```

---

Alternatively, it can be set to your favorite editor like this:

```
export EDITOR=nano
```

or

```
export EDITOR=leafpad
```

---

**Once the EDITOR is specified in the environment, `crontab -e` uses it.**

Short and sweet.

---

To make this change take effect at login this line can be appended to 
`/home/username/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 2):

> `crontab -e` defaults to using `vi` for editing.

Not really. Per `man crontab`:

> The `-e` option is used to edit the current crontab using the editor specified by the `VISUAL` or `EDITOR` environment variables. After you exit from the editor, the modified crontab will be installed automatically. If neither of the environment variables is defined, then the default editor `/usr/bin/editor` is used.

`/usr/bin/editor` is a symlink managed by the alternatives system: it points to `/etc/alternatives/editor`, which is itself a symlink to the actual editor. It does not really have a "default" value, as its value at any time depends on the editors which are actually installed on the system. You can obtain its current value with `ls -l /etc/alternatives/editor`, and modify it with `sudo update-alternatives --config editor`.

Comment: Makes sense. I'm glad I can override it by exporting EDITOR to get the editor I want. Just a single line of code in the right place, without worries.

Answer (score 0):

in ubuntu 18.04
Right click on file select `properties` select third tab `open with` add new and set it as default.

Comment: The question is specific to the crontab files (stored in /var/spool/cron/crontabs) and the manual pages for `crontab` indicate that is not a good idea to edit these files directly.  The method that you are proposing would do just that, however.