# How do I change the editor form vim to nano?

Tags: command-line, apt, sudo, nano

While using the command `sudo apt edit-sources`, accidentally chose vim instead of nano and don't know how to change it. I used `sudo update-alternatives --config editor` but it doesn't change the editor I use in the `sudo apt edit-sources` command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the default text editor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13447/how-do-i-change-the-default-text-editor)

Comment: apt uses `/usr/bin/select-editor` (it creates a file in HOME .selected_editor, if you delete it you will get to choose again)

Comment: I can't find HOME.selected_editor so I deleted select-editor in /usr/bin/select-editor but even that dosent seem to work.

Comment: `apt-get --reinstall install sensible-utils` will give you `select-editor`  back, run it to get the menu.

Comment: In short, apt edit-sources uses `Dir::Bin::Editor` as default editor, which defaults to `sensible-editor`, this is a shell wrapper trying to make sense of which editor to use if neither EDITOR nor SELECTED_EDITOR is set `sensible-editor` will try to start `select-editor` which creates and sources the file `~/.selected_editor` before calling the *selected editor*, I think the order is $VISUAL, $EDITOR, $SELECTED_EDITOR and last editor.

Comment: sorry `nano` is last

Comment: I really appreciate all the information about the order of completion and that command did bring back 'select-editor' and when I ran it I got to choose again but the problem is still there. When I run 'sudo apt edit-sources' vim opens. I am not that familiar with vim so I am kinda stuck and I think I will reinstall the OS if can't fix it.

Comment: If you ran this with sudo, look for the file in root's home directory not your own.